# How to remove certain part of files with some conditions, sed or awk?

Tags: awk, sed

Hi I am very new on AWK or SED.

But here is what I need.

I have dozens of files whic contains

```
<li>
   <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn-circle" style="width: 10px;height: 12px;"></a> Online
```

Shall I use awk or sed with certain way to collectively locate all the files with this snipet and remove this part in the file?

Could anyone shred a light, thanks in advance.

Comment: I would use a DOM + XPath for that. Don't handle XML with regexes.

Comment: If you are looking to process pieces of HTML, awk and sed are not the recommended tools for the job. Better to use an HTML parser (perl and python have these) or if your files are valid XML, something like xmlstarlet. It would be useful if you showed a more complete example of your input and desired output.

Comment: sed is for substitutions on singe lines. Your snippet is 2 lines and therefore sed is not the right tool for the job. Awk could handle it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ cat file
now is the
winter
<li>
   <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn-circle" style="width: 10px;height: 12px;"></a> Online
of our
discontent
```

.

```
$ cat rmv 
<li>
   <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn-circle" style="width: 10px;height: 12px;"></a> Online
```

.

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= 'NR==FNR{str=$0; next} s=index($0,str){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) substr($0,s+length(str))} 1' rmv file
now is the
winter
of our
discontent
```